# O R possui algum comando semelhante ao IN do SAS?

Tags: r, sas

O R possui algum comando semelhante ao IN do SAS?

Segue um exemplo em código SAS:

IF variavel1 IN (4,5,6,7) THEN variavel2 = 1;

Ou seja, se a variável1 assumir os valores de 4 a 7, à variável2 é atribuído o valor 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode também utilizar o operador [`%in%`](http://dr-k-lo.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/in-in-r-underused-in-operator.html)

```
variavel1 <- 5  
if (variavel1 %in% c(4, 5, 6, 7)) {
   variavel2 <- 1
}
```

[Exemplo funcional](http://ideone.com/6IxnUj)

Comment: Ambas as formas funcionaram perfeitamente, muito obrigado!

Comment: Olá Henrique, não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta que você considerar mais adequada (todas as outras respostas úteis podem ser presenteadas com um voto positivo).

Comment: Isso também vale para as suas [outras perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17284/henrique-pizarro?tab=questions).

Comment: Obrigado pelo aviso!

Comment: De nada Henrique. Sempre que tiver alguma dúvida ou sugestão sobre o site pode utilizar o [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/). Abraços.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta a função is.element .

```
var1 <- 1
if (is.element(var1, c(1, 2, 4))) { 
    var2 <- 1
    print(var2)
}
```

Comment: Então e se `var1 = 5`, que valor assume `var2`?

Comment: @PauloCardoso, editei a resposta. Agora var2 só imprime caso a condição seja verdadeira. De qualquer maneira caso o elemento não esteja na lista retornará falso. exemplo: is.element(5, c(1, 2, 4)).